# Lotus Domino public key not found

Tags: ibm-domino

Getting failed to authenticate: public key not found in the domino directory for all users when trying to access a single Domino server from a client.  All users can access the other servers in our Domino domain just fine, just not this one server.  Nothing has changed besides the server shutting down last night and being brought back up this morning. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Shut down the server, run nfixup names.nsf from the notes program directory.

Answer (score 0):

restore servers names.nsf from the last known good backup.